# How to auto turn on 'Stock Availability' to 'In Stock' after Quantity is updated from 0 to any number greater?

Tags: product, quantity

I am working on a store with thousands of products. I have noticed that when product Quantity is zero (or manually turned to Zero) the Stock Availability goes 'Out of Stock' however when we update the product Quantity to number greater then zero like 10,15 or 200 the 'Stock Availability' stays 'Out of Stock' unless and until manually changed to 'In Stock' so that the product appears on frontend.
I want the 'Stock Availability' to Auto turned to 'In Stock' as we update the Quantity to number greater then Zero. The Quantity in my case gets its values from the store inventory software we don't change it manually.

Comment: how you update the stock quantity? manually or by script

Comment: Until now we were doing it through a php script.But we are about to purchase an extension which will sync products according to our stores inventory.

Comment: In script itself, you can change the stock availabillity. Did you tried that?

Comment: Yeah i guess theres an option in script.But my store owners want it to be predefined without having to change it again and again.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Magento event `catalog_product_save_after`.

write this in your `config.xml` file

```
<global>
         <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Magetest_test_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>changeStockStatus</method>
                    </Save_product_data>
                </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
```

Create an observer method `changeStockStatus()` at below location `your_module/Model/Observer.php` that does the following on event `catalog_product_save_after`.

```
public function changeStockStatus($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $stockData = $product->getStockData();

    if ( $product && $stockData['qty'] > 0) {
        $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getEntityId()); // Load the stock for this product
        $stock->setData('is_in_stock', 1); // Set the Product to InStock                               
        $stock->save(); // Save
    }
}
```

Comment: Manashvi can you tell where do i have to place this method in magento files? I am just a newbie

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: Hello Mashavi i tried following as you wrote but its not working.i cleared my cache after making the module with your files and then tried it on localhost by turning quantity of one of product to zero,then increasing it so it shows on frontend but it does not.

Comment: Please also note that the observer.php gives error on line 3,could that be the issue?

Comment: Hi, this script will work when you manually change the stock of the product or if any custom script updates the stock. Also can you let me know what is the error in the observer.php

Comment: I tried it with manually changing product qty but it gives no output.can you check again please?

Comment: As for obersevr.php the error was due to closing php tag

Comment: check my updated ans. It's working for me. Make sure the code in the observer.php is executed when the product is saved

Comment: Alright i will re-checkb it once i get home.atm im online from my phone.Thank you a million.

Comment: I have followed word to word your post.unfortunately its still not working for me.would you please allow me to send you my zipped version of the module to make sure it is correct,please?

Comment: There were some issues with both of your config.xml and Observer.php files.I fixed them with the help of another user and now its up and running. I will post the corrected versions soon.Thanks a lot for the help.Stay blessed :) –

Comment: @TallalHassan can you please post your code. i am trying here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89968/auto-changing-the-stock-availability-from-out-of-stock-to-in-stock-on-quan/89975?noredirect=1#comment119864_89975 but its not working for me